# Laravel | Route not defined

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a problem in my Route.

I see this error:

```
 Route [utilizadores.editar] not defined
```

The error occurs on the page when I try to update the data in my DB.
My Route:

```
Route::put('Utilizadores/{item}', [FuncionarioController::class, 'editar'])->name('utilizadores.editar');
Route::get('Utilizadores/{item}/edit', [FuncionarioController::class, 'edit'])->name('utilizadores.edit');
```

My controller:

```
 public function editar(Request $request, funcionario $item){
     
    $item->nome = $request->nome;
    $item->email = $request->email;
    $item->telefone = $request->telefone;

    $item->foto = $request->foto;

    $item->data_nasc = $request->data_nasc;
    $item->nacionalidade = $request->nacionalidade;
    $item->n_cartao_cc = $request->n_cartao_cc;
    $item->nif = $request->nif;
    $item->morada = $request->morada;
    $item->n_porta = $request->n_porta;
    $item->localidade = $request->localidade;
    $item->concelho = $request->concelho;
    $item->distrito = $request->distrito;
    $item->cp = $request->cp;

    $item->data_entrada = $request->data_entrada;
    $item->funcao = $request->funcao;
    $item->estado = $request->estado;

   // $item->n_ferias_disponiveis = $request->n_ferias_disponiveis; 
    
   // $item->data_registo = $now;

    dd($item);

    $item->save();
    return redirect()->route('utilizadores.index');   
   
    }
```

My View:

```
<form class="needs-validation" method="POST" action="{{route('utilizadores.editar',$item->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
@method('put')
```

Where am I wrong? I have other pages like this done and it works.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Edit: My php artisan route:list

```
  |        | DELETE   | Utilizadores/{item}             | utilizadores.delete         | App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController@delete             | web
                     |
  |        | PUT      | Utilizadores/{item}             | utilizadores.editar_perfil  | App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController@editar_perfil      | web
                     |
  |        | GET|HEAD | Utilizadores/{item}/delete      | utilizadores.modal          | App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController@modal              | web
                     |
  |        | GET|HEAD | Utilizadores/{item}/edit        | utilizadores.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController@edit               | web
                     |
  |        | GET|HEAD | Utilizadores/{item}/edit_perfil | utilizadores.edit_perfil    | App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController@edit_perfil        | web
                     |
  |        | PUT      | Utilizadores/{item}/editpass    | utilizadores.passwordeditar | App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController@passwordeditar     | web
```

Comment: Code looks correct; do you have any kind of Caching that could make that view unavailable until you refresh it? Also, run `php artisan route:list` to see the full list of Routes; make sure `utilizadores.editar` is listed.

Comment: I see utilizadores.edit but utilizadores.editar doesn't show . Is there any reason for this to happen?

Comment: Hmm, not with the code you posted... Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72019375/edit) and add the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: You are literally defining the route 2 times, you can see you have `utilizadores.editar_perfil` that is using the same URL and same controller and method, so I am assuming you are defining that after your `.editar`. Another recommendation is do not write code in portuguese, ALWAYS use English, and follow the "laravel convention" for URLs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller, why are you mixing portuguese (`editar`) with english (`edit`)? It is very confusing and weird

Answer (score 1):

Just swap edit and editar route. Something like this

```php
Route::get('Utilizadores/{item}/edit', [FuncionarioController::class, 'edit'])->name('utilizadores.edit');
Route::put('Utilizadores/{item}', [FuncionarioController::class, 'editar'])->name('utilizadores.editar');
```

Or better, use resource controller for simpler Route file

```php
Route::resource('utilizadores', FuncionarioController::class);
```

Keep in mind that you will tweak some function name and route file

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two identical routes for the same method/path. It is apparent in route:list that you already have a route registered for `put('Utilizadores/{item}')` with a different name `(utilizadores.editar_perfil),` therefore,

```
Route::put('Utilizadores/{item}', 
    [FuncionarioController::class, 'editar'])
    ->name('utilizadores.editar');
```

is not being registered, so you get that error when you try to insert `{{ route('utilizadores.editar',$item->id) }}` in your view.

Answer (score -1):

First look to your route list using below command

```
php artisan route:list
```

If the routes exists then hit this command :

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: I try code php artisan route:list  But my route doesn't show. 
The route is exactly the same as the others existing in the same project.
Is there any reason for this to happen?

Comment: Check your web.php file

Comment: But this route is the same as all the others that already exist

Comment: Try : php artisan route:clear